# The solutions of a system of differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Let $P(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}^{\frac{x^2}{y-x}}$ for $x \neq y$ and using the proper limits $P(x,y)=e^{-x}$ for $x=y $, $P(x,y)=0$ for $x\neq0, y=0,$ and $P(x,y)=1$ for $x=0, y\neq0.$

Consider this system of differential equations:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} x(t) = a(t) - c\,\left( 1-P(x(t), y(t) \right),$$
$$ \frac{d}{dt} y(t) = a(t) + c -c\,(2x+1)\,(\left( 1-P(x(t), y(t) \right).$$

Where $\bf{a(t)\ge 0}$ is a piecewise continuous function and $\bf{c>0}$ is some constant.

Assuming $\bf{y(0)\ge x(0) \ge 0}$, the solution $(x(t), y(t))$ of this system of differential equations satisfy:

1 - $x(t) \ge 0$,

2 - $y(t) \ge 0$,

3 - $y(t) \ge x(t)$.

Does anyone know how to show this?

The problem is here when $x(t)=0$ and $a(t)=0$ at the same time ( because in this case $x(t)=0$ and $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=0$) Then I don't know how to show $x(t)$ remains non-negative after that?

Similarly if $x(t)=y(t)=0$ then also $\frac{d}{dt}(x(t)-y(t))=0$ and then it's not obvious $y(t) \ge x(t)$ after that (we can't use higher derivatives because they may not exist as $a(t)$ may not be differentiable).

Comment: @ username I want to show if $x(t)=0$ at some point $t$, then it remains non-negative in a neighborhood $(t, t+\delta t)$. I didn't get your comment. Can you please explain more?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were saying. Forget my comment.

Comment: The formula for $P(x,y)$ is not clear for me. Are there some missing brackets? Brackets would make the formula more clear.